# How to automatically add a row (aka insert mode) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

What's a way to put Google Sheets into auto-row-insert mode (such that  each time after I finish typing the contents in a cell and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, I do not have to do <Insert Row> , ie <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> on a ChromeOS browser)?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. The keyboard shortcut you mention does not work on all systems. Please edit your question and specify what you want to happen when you press **Enter**. Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) to show a visual demonstration. See if the [autoInsertCells_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135707345) script works for you.

Comment: @doubleunary, edited

Comment: For some reason on *this* system (which I suspect is the same one), `alt` is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Insert Mode / Auto-Insert Mode

I have never heard of a mode where every time you complete editing a cell, Google sheets automatically inserts a new row above that same cell.

Sounds like you insert rows often and find your current approach time consuming.  In order to increase the speed of inserting a row using the keyboard, first ensure `compatible shortcuts` are enabled in Google Sheets:

1. Click on **Keyboard Shortcuts** in the **Help** menu
   *or*   <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>
   *or*   <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> then <kbd>K</kbd>
2. Check that **Enable compatible spreadsheet shortcuts** is enabled.
3. Insert Row

   - **Above**: <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd>     *or*    <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd>
   - **Below**:  <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> then <kbd>B</kbd>     *or*    <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> then <kbd>B</kbd>

Some Resources:

- **View Compatible Shortcuts** link in **Keyboard Shortcuts** <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>
- Google Support Article: [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110)

Comment: interesting idea/hack. Btw is  there one for Insert Below instead of Insert Above?

Comment: I've updated answer to include `insert below` option.